# How to make this code sequential without touching outer function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I need such sequence:

lurks in the shadows;
the end

How to achieve such result without touching 'sequential' function?

Achieve sequential run

```
function who() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('');
    }, 200);
  });
}

function what() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('lurks');
    }, 300);
  });
}

function where() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('in the shadows');
    }, 500);
  });
}

async function msg() {
  const a = await who();
  const b = await what();
  const c = await where();

  console.log(`${ a } ${ b } ${ c }`);
}

function sequential(){
    msg();
    console.log('the end');
}

sequential();
```

I need such sequence:

```
lurks in the shadows
the end
```

How to achieve such result without touching 'sequential' function?

Current result is:

```
the end
lurks in the shadows
```

Comment: You can't. You need to wait for `msg` to finish first. You could also just move all the code inside one function.

Comment: Is changing it to `async function sequential(){
    await msg();
    console.log('the end');
}` really a problem? I don't see why touching `sequential` shouldn't be allowed here.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function who(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data + '');
    }, 200);
  });
}

function what(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data + 'lurks');
    }, 300);
  });
}

function where(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data + 'in the shadows');
    }, 500);
  });
}

function msg() {
  return who('')
  .then(what)
  .then(where);
}

function sequential(){
    return msg()
    .then((respo) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(respo));
      console.log('the end');
    });
    
}

sequential();
```

You can do this!

Comment: **`without touching 'sequential' function`**

Comment: If you don't want to touch `sequential` function, you have to move "the end" console into `msg` function

Comment: that would still **`touch`** sequential function - the answer to the question as given is, and will always be, **you can't**

Comment: Then you can't do!